# how do I right justify some text to other text that is centered

Tags: css, alignment

I want to have a customer testimonial quote centered in the middle of a page.  The quote might be arbitrary length, but doesn't span two lines.  Then I want a new line and then the name of the person that provided the testimonial, just under the testimonial but right justified.

```
<div class="quote">
 "Wow!  Thanks, create customer service."
</div>
<div class="source">
  -- John S. - California
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.quote {text-align:center}
.source {text-align:right; padding-right:300px;}
```

How do I align the source so that I works for arbitrary length of quotes?

Comment: That looks like `blockquote` content that's been marked up with a div.  Also, the `cite` tag exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do, probably:

HTML:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <span class="quote">
            "Wow!  Thanks, create customer service."
            <cite>
                 -- John S. - California
            </cite>
        </span> 
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
blockquote {
    text-align: center;
}
.quote {
    position: relative;
}
cite {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: -25px;
     text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This works.  I didn't know you could use position:relative in a span element, which is inline.  This makes sense.  Although, the `<p>` tag isn't needed is it?

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup a bit and nest the source into the quote.

```
<div class="quote">
    "Wow!  Thanks, create customer service."
    <div class="source">
         -- John S. - California
    </div> 
</div>
```

The CSS for it:

```
.quote { 
  display:table;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.quote .source {
  text-align:right;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PskLe/) for it.

Comment: This is pretty clever. Definitely better than either two answers (including mine!). Big +1.

Comment: This answer works on modern browsers, but I neglected to say I had to support IE7 still (which display:table is not performing correctly).  THiCE answer works on ie7, though has padding issues I need to work on.

Comment: @sketchfemme in cases like this I would always prefer a conditional stylesheet for ie7, so a mix of both solutions would do it for me. Anyway the HTML of THiCE is definitely the best.

Answer (score 0):

Basically: you can't without going too ugly and hack-y with your markup. (See THiCE's answer for such a solution).

I do **not** recommend this, but if you're okay with using JavaScript, then this is fairly simple: (below uses jQuery, but can be achieved without it)

```
$(".quote").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next().css({"padding-right": ($this.parent().width() - $this.width()) / 2});
});
```

If you don't want to use JavaScript and don't want to go hack-y, I suggest you rethink your layout just a bit.

Comment: That's not ugly! I've improved my answer :) If you'd like to go hacky or ugly, use javascript for layout purposes....

Comment: @THiCE Your improved answer is nice :) It still is hacky though; absolute positioning is generally.. um, well it just feels wrong. I do **NOT** recommend using JavaScript for layout; I was just presenting another method if the OP insists on the layout in mind.

Comment: I think absolute positioning is a way to keep full control of the position of elements without misusing them. I'm not a big fan of `display: table-cell` to achieve certain layout wishes, you are not a big fan of absolute positioning :)

Comment: @THiCE Yep. :) Although I have to say the third answer looks promising -- beware, uses `display: table;`! Although I think the same could be achieved using `display: inline-block;` (with a tiny modification).